# How to bridge two PulseAudio outputs?

Tags: pulse-audio, a2dp, jackd

I have bluetooth headphones which can't be connected to JackAudio so I thought that PulseAudio is able to duplicate output from integrated audio to A2DP headphones. The question is - is it possible? And if yes - how?

Comment: Hello there. If your audio works with the speaker output then you could convert the 3.5mm output of audio to bluetooth for your headphones? A device such as this would do the job: https://www.amazon.ca/Bluetooth-Transmitter-Receiver-TaoTronics-Simultaneously/dp/B013ULOP10/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=bluetooth+transmitter&qid=1579887797&sr=8-3

Comment: @NatsuKage While that is a solution to a problem and is appreciated, I still am interested if it's possible via software only.

Comment: I am not knowledgeable on Linux, thus why I'm suggesting a workaround. Maybe this can help you for dual outputs: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=240935  as well as :  https://askubuntu.com/questions/78174/play-sound-through-two-or-more-outputs-devices

Comment: perhaps the loopback module could do it.